# pcap monitor mode available but doesn't work

Tags: wifi, pcap, openwrt, sniffing

**Context:**

I am writing a program, which uses pcap to capture packets in the monitor mode on the openwrt router with ar9331 chip. 
I tested the program on a desktop with pcap 1.1 (which existed in my openwrt version) and found an issue: pcap_can_set_rfmon returned true, pcap_set_rfmon returned success, but attempt to activate capture resulted in “monitor mode isn't supported” error.

Google search showed a bug report of similar issue with wireshark. One of the comments says that with some wi-fi devices the issue is caused by an old version of pcap, which uses old version of another lib.
I updated pcap version to 1.5.3 and the issue was resolved.

**Problem:**
The issue appears again when I port our program to Openwrt. But now update of libpcap package to version 1.5.3 from newer openwrt branch doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the libpcap monitor-mode code on Linux works best when libpcap is linked with libnl, and it's often not linked with libnl for various reasons (including problems with a program using libpcap and libnl, and linked with a different version of libnl than the one with which libpcap is linked).

This needs to be redone in libpcap.  It may end up being done with a "helper process" that libpcap runs to do various things; that would also improve cleanup if the program using libpcap exits abnormally and would allow packet capture operations requiring special privileges to be confined to the helper process rather than requiring the program using libpcap to run with those privileges.  This is on my rather long to-do list.

The best workaround is probably to use airmon-ng to turn monitor mode on, as described in [the Wireshark Wiki page on Wi-Fi capturing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Linux).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't achieve success with libpcap and libnl, so i used part of horst's sniffing code.

Comment: @EgorDudyak; I am having the same issue. I always get an error "That device doesn't support monitor mode" on openwrt. How did you fixed that?

Comment: @haccks I didn't fix. Maybe problem was resolved in new version of pcap, i don't know. I just used some code from [horst-https://github.com/br101/horst](https://github.com/br101/horst) instead of using pcap. As i remember this code work with driver directly.

Comment: @EgorDudyak; Which part didi you used? I am capturing packet using libpcap.

Comment: @haccks I cut off everything except for frame capturing code, you can look at my [repo](https://github.com/3Gorec/rssi_sniffer).

Comment: @EgorDudyak; OK. In that code you didn't used libpcap. Is that code working on OpenWrt?

Comment: @haccks Yes, on ar9331 and not only. This is my [openwrt packckage repo](https://github.com/3Gorec/rssi_sniffer_package).

Comment: @EgorDudyak; I am also using ar9331. Could you please tell me how good it is capturing packets? (As compare to tcpdump).

Comment: @haccks I don't know what you mean good. It capturing. I need only headers in my task. I didn't use tcpdump. I don't remember does horst code capturing payload. You can inspect and test horst or my code and find answer.

Comment: @EgorDudyak; I only need to capture, rssi, noise and ssid of the station. No payload. I have working code for this and I used libpcap. But the problem is it is not working on openwrt.

Comment: @haccks I you wouldn't be so lazy and spend 2 minutes to look at my repo you find out that my code do almost exactly what you need.

Comment: @EgorDudyak; hahaaa. Every programmer is lazy! The thing is I have to go through all those files to see what is going under the hood and that's of course is time taking. But I will go through it and will let you know for sure :)

Comment: @EgorDudyak; I took an overview and I can see many fields can be extracted from the code in your repository. Is it possible to capture only probe and association requests?

Comment: @haccks I look quickly and see no problems, just add filter by packet type in  packet processing (in local_receive_packet() after parse_packet()). For example.

Comment: @EgorDudyak; OK. I will try and will let you know.